# Create VBA class in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, vba, class

Is it possible (using COM and regasm.exe) to have a vba function call a vb.net function - which creates the class in vb.net and then passes the class back to vba, where it is recognised as a vba class?

In VBA, I can work with classes by using Insert>Class Module. I have set up a function that creates a class.

```
Private length As Double
Private height As Double
Public Sub init(ByRef hgt As Double)
  height = hgt
  length = dbl_height()
End Sub

Public Function dbl_height()
  dbl_height = height * 2
End Function
```

I can initialize it accordingly using this function:

```
Public Function CreateClassFunction(foo As Integer)
  Dim my_rect As Rectangle
  Set my_rect = New Rectangle
  my_rect.init (foo)
  Set CreateClassFunction = my_rect
End Function
```

I can also do the same thing in vb.net with virtually identical code.

```
Public Class Rectangle
   Private length As Double
   Private height As Double
   Public Sub init(ByRef hgt As Double)
     height = hgt
     length = dbl_height()
   End Sub

   Public Function dbl_height()
     dbl_height = height * 2
   End Function
End Class
```

where this vb.net function creates the class:

```
Public Function CreateClassFunction(foo As Integer) As Rectangle
    Dim my_rect As Rectangle
    my_rect = New Rectangle
    my_rect.init(foo)
    CreateClassFunction = my_rect
End Function
```

I can pull in a Variant/Object/Rectangle into vba using:

```
Function MyCreateClass(a As Double)
  Dim classLib As New MyAnalytics.Class1
  Set MyCreateClass = classLib.CreateClassFunction(a)
End Function
```

However this object does not have the height or length variables. (It says "no variables" on the watch window)

Edit:

Amended code as per Mat's Mug answer:

```
Public Class Rectangle
Private plength As Double
Private pheight As Double
Public Property length() As Double
    Get
        Return plength
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Double)
        plength = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property height() As Double
    Get
        Return pheight
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Double)
        pheight = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub init(ByRef hgt As Double)
    height = hgt
    length = dbl_height()
End Sub

Public Function dbl_height()
    dbl_height = height * 2
End Function

End Class
```

and testing in VBA:

```
Function MyCreateClass(a As Double)
  Dim classLib As New MyAnalytics.Class1

  Set MyCreateClass = classLib.CreateClassFunction(a)

  Debug.Print MyCreateClass.Height()
  Debug.Print MyCreateClass.length()

  MyCreateClass.Height = 30
  MyCreateClass.length = 20

  Debug.Print MyCreateClass.Height()
  Debug.Print MyCreateClass.length()

  MyCreateClass.init (100)
  Debug.Print MyCreateClass.Height()
  Debug.Print MyCreateClass.length()


End Function
```

Comment: The `length` and `height` properties are private so they are not exposed beyond the class.

Comment: They're not properties, they're fields. Don't make fields public. Ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't be *recognized as a VBA class* - it's *not* a VBA class, but a COM object.

Your `Rectangle` class has *private fields*. Private fields are, well, `Private`. This is, roughly, what VBA sees:

```
Public Class Rectangle
   Sub init(ByRef hgt As Double)    
   Function dbl_height()
End Class
```

Where are the fields?

```
Private length As Double
Private height As Double
```

You haven't exposed them - as far as VBA goes, they don't exist.

Now, you could make them `Public` - but then you would be breaking encapsulation by exposing fields; **don't do that!**

Expose property getters instead, and setters if you want VBA code to be able to change the `Length` and `Height` properties of a `Rectangle` instance.

Comment: Thank you @mats-mug. Is it possible to see the properties in the Watches window when debugging? They are accessible in code and the Immediate window.